# Multiple columns in subquery using Firebird

Tags: firebird

I'm searching the way to do this in Firebird

```
 SELECT  field1, field2, field3
 FROM table1
 WHERE (field1, field2) IN
            (SELECT fieldA, fieldB
             FROM table2
             WHERE fieldA = 'XXXXX')
```

I have searched a solutions and I found some for others databases but not for Firebird.

Regards

Comment: Unfortunately, Firebird does not support row values. You'd need to exists instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 SELECT  field1, field2, field3
 FROM table1
 WHERE exists
 (SELECT * 
  FROM table2
  WHERE fieldA = 'XXXXX' and fieldA=field1 and field2=fieldB)
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low-value on Stackoverflow. Even if a solution is seemingly basic/intuitive/self-explanatory to you, there will be researchers that are not familiar with the technique/syntax. Every answer should include an explanation with the intent to educate/empower the OP and thousands of future researchers. Remember, this is never a 1-to-1 interaction -- because old pages are used to close new pages, this answer may be integral in helping users with similar questions as well.

Answer (score 1):

Firebird does not support multiple columns in subquery, unfortunately.